# How to use strncmp function for an array with multi-dimensional in CAPL?

Tags: arrays, string-comparison, capl, canoe

I have an array of string in buffer (`char Buffer_DTC[2000]`) and I have declared multi-dimensional  character array in CAPL language like (`char MY_DTC[2][5] = {"DTC1","DTC2"}`). Now I want to compare every string of `MY_DTC` with `Buffer_DTC` array. How can I do that? I already tried with strncmp function but it did not work. Here is the code for reference

```
  char Buffer_DTC[200000];
  char My_DTC[2][5] = {"DTC1",""DTC2};
  int i;
  int j;


  DiagGetComplexParameter(this,"ListOfDTC", i, "DTC" , TextBuffer, elCount(TextBuffer)); // get the corresponding DTC text

  snprintf(TextBuffer,elCount(TextBuffer),"\n %06X ",DTC);
     

      for(i=0;i<elcount(Buffer_DTC);i++)
      {
        for(j=0;j<elcount(MY_DTC);j++)
        {
          if(strncmp(TextBuffer,arr_dtc,strlen(TextBuffer))==0)
          {
            write("DTC are same");
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Try to print both `TextBuffer` and `arr_dtc` just before the `if` statement. Print the characters enclosed in "<>" and check if they are actually the same. I see that you are even printing some new line character using snprintf.

Comment: What is `TextBuffer`? What is `arr_dtc`? Shoudn't you be using `i` and `j` somewhere inside your for-loop?